# Alter ctools_ajax_command_redirect()

Tags: ajax, webforms, redirection, forms, chaos-tool-suite

My problem is redirect after webform submission.
So I have a webform node and AJAX on this submit button (hello "Webform Ajax").
How I do redirect:
I'm just using hook_form_alter() and add to this webform "submit" special redirect function. It must be make redirect after webform submission.
In general it works if I doesn't use the "Webform Ajax" module. 
But I need use the "Webform Ajax" (Do not ask me why) I'm catching a mistake.
In code I found how the "Webform Ajax" makes redirect: ctools_ajax_command_redirect() function.
Well the QUESTION: How can I "alter" this functionality?

Any Ideas how I can make redirect after submit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and unset the `$form['#submit']`. Then you add your own submit handler by using `$form['#submit'][] = '_my_callback';` THen in your callback just copy the code of the Ajax redirect and alter it to your needs.